# MAXIMUM CURSORS EXCEEDING WITH DATABASE LINK IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g, plsqldeveloper

I have a stored procedure as follows, When I am executing ths procedure, every time 1 cursor increasing in remote server. How to Solve this.

```
create or replace function transactionaldatarecovery
   (i_tablename in varchar2) 
return varchar2 
as
    v_Num Number(3):=0; 
    v_SQLStmt Varchar2(2000);
    ret_status Varchar2(100);

begin

              v_sqlstmt := 'insert into '||i_tablename||
                           ' select *  from '||i_tablename||'@RECY_DBLINK a '||
                           ' where  not exists( select 1 '||
                           '                    from   '||i_tablename||' b'||
                           '                    where  B.sno = A.sno' ;

        Execute immediate v_SQLstmt;

return 'Success';
end transactionaldatarecovery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you commit after running the function? It should free opened cursor on remote DB.

Comment: yes, Now I got the solution. When Accessind DBlink every time a cursor is Opening in Remote Server. When we Close database link with ALTER Statement then Cursor is Closing

Comment: ALTER is a DDL statement and makes commit before it is executed. You may try to do just COMMIT and check that opened cursor is fried.